# I need help fixing this bug with KineticJS - issue with scaling on browser zoom out

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Alright so here I have a simulation:

http://www.cs.uml.edu/~jperreau/EQL/galton/

which is not actually the latest version of the simulation. The latest version of it can be found at:

http://github.com/Pkthunder/EQL

Anyhow. The bug... when the browser is zoomed at 100% or more, the bug does not show up, and this simulation looks like this (Take note that i turned off the residual lines to simplify the image):

i.imgur.com/xkRccSN.png

Now, the bug appears when zoomed out more than 100%, and looks like this (note that the zoom on the browser is at 50%):

i.imgur.com/uJizmbP.png

And finally, the size of the patch of rectangle that shows the simulation without the "ghost" balls decreases as the zoom increases. So for example, below is a zoom of 75%. As you can see the rectangle of "good" simulation is greater than that in the 50% zoom:

i.imgur.com/MKWs9db.png

Some last remarks that might help with debugging:
-If the browser starts at a zoom of 100% or more, and is THEN zoomed down to something less than 100% WITHOUT A PAGE RELOAD, then the bug does not appear
-I suspect it has something to do with the instantiation of the canvases of the Layers
-If I set the height and width attributes of the canvas objects on the page as the height and width of the canvas element:

&ltcanvas width="613" height="311" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1226px; height: 622px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"&gt

i.e. set the height and width of the style to be the height and width of the element, the canvas shrinks to be the exact size of the "good" patch of the simulation

-To answer some follow up questions I received:
A. What browser are you using? Does it happen in every browser? 
This bug has occurred in the following browsers, on both MacOS and Windows platforms: FireFox, Chrome, Safari, IE (not sure what version). All of the browsers were upgraded to their latest versions

B. Why exactly do you care about the windows zoom for the project?
This simulation is being presented at a conference in Atlanta in front of a lot of big whigs in the world of Mathematics, in hopes that one of them will fund the creation of an exhibit at the Museum of Mathematics. This code is a simulation of what the future exhibit will model, which is a "Programmable Galton Board." Anyhow, we (the research group) want to be sure that this bug will not show up on the day of presentation, as a peace of mind. Because it would be awful to get on stage and realize that the projection screen distorts dimensions in a way that we would need to zoom out in order to run the simulation, and BOOM. The bug.

Thank you all! This simulation needs to be done within a week so any immediate answers are greatly appreciated !

Comment: Interesting app!  But I'm not getting your misbehavior in Chrome33, FF27 or IE11 while using:  www.cs.uml.edu/~jperreau/EQL/galton/

Comment: did you zoom out and reload the page at a zoom less than 100% and then try running the simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is a known issue with Kineticjs. https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/753 explains the problem in detail, however if you place `Kinetic.pixelRatio = 1;` in your code before you create a stage or layer object it should fix the problem